# Expression related to dual norm on bounded linear functionals

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, normed-spaces

Given a vector space $V$ and a norm $\|\cdot\|$ on $V$, the dual norm $\|\cdot\|^*$ on $V^*$ is given by

$\|f\|^* = \sup \left\{\frac{f(v)}{\|v\|}\right\}$

over all nonzero vectors $v$.

I've found myself in a situation where I instead need to compute the related function

$p(f) = \sup \left\{\frac{f(v)}{e^{\|v\|}}\right\}$

Is there any sort of technique that will help me start tackling this?

I do see two useful things about this:

1. $\frac{f(v)}{\|v\|} \gt \frac{f(v)}{e^{\|v\|}}$
2. $\frac{f(kv)}{e^{\|kv\|}} \leq \frac{f(v)}{e^{\|v\|}}$ iff $k \geq 1$

but I cannot figure out how to use this to make any headway on the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that
$$
\left(\frac{x}{e^x}\right)'=\frac{e^x(1-x)}{e^{2x}}
$$
vanishes at $x=1$ (which is a maximum of the function). Hence,
$$
p(f)=\frac1e\sup_{\|v\|=1}f(v)=\frac1e\|f\|^*.
$$

Comment: Thanks. I did just realize I should have modified my question to handle an extra wrinkle: I need to do this over only those vectors in $\Bbb R^n$ with integer coordinates (and only for finite-dimensional vector spaces, to be specific). If I'm dividing by $||v||$, this works out exactly the same as the case where I look at all vectors, so the "integer coordinates only" part doesn't matter. But now it may be different. Do you see any obvious way to extend your idea to this scenario, or should it be a new question?

Comment: The part of integer coordinates shouldn't change anything, because any direction can be approximated by vectors with integer coordinates. But the part of approximating by finite-dimensional subspaces may matter, my impression. Perhaps indeed it should be another question. Sorry.

Comment: No, I didn't mean approximating by finite-dimensional subspaces, I just meant I'd be happy to answer this for only those simpler scenarios where $V$ itself is finite-dimensional. But I'm not sure I see your reasoning regarding every direction being approximates by vectors with integer coordinates - yes, that's true, but for some arbitrary integer vector v, v/exp(||v||) no longer lies on the unit circle.

Comment: I see it now, I will think about it, I will let you know if I see some way out.